# Валидация JSP формы с помощью JS (i18)

Tags: javascript, java-ee, jsp, валидация, jstl

Для интернационализации использую `<fmt:message key="m"/>` - jstl

При невалидной странице хочу выполнить функцию

```
function showError(container) {
    var msgElem = document.createElement("p");
    msgElem.innerHTML = "<fmt:message key=\"error\"/> ";
    container.appendChild(msgElem);
}
```

В container должно появиться `<p><fmt:message key="error"/></p>`

Получаю `<p><fmt:message key="error"></fmt:message></p>`

Кто-то может сказать что я делаю не так?

P.S. страница не HTML, а JSP. Да, я понимаю, что fmt - не тэг html. Это тэг jstl, который работает на jsp

Comment: JSTL работает тогда когда идет формирование страницы, после он отдаёт html код. Следовательно вам это нужно грузить с сервера.

Comment: А как загрузить с сервера, если валидацию я делаю на клиенте

Comment: делать валидацию на сервере

Answer (score 0):

На стороне сервера сгенерировать скрытый тег `p` с локализованной строкой, а в js-коде просто делать его видимым в случае необходимости. Или сделать сервлет отдающий localized.js, содержащий словарь локализованных строк.